# How can I run a game where the players are lesser deities

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, religions-and-deities

I am going to be DMing a game in which the players all start as lesser gods in a pantheon of gods with 3 tiers. They start at the lowest tier in each of four branches of the pantheon, life, death, trade, and knowledge. Are there official rules for players as gods in 5e preferably or in earlier editions as well?

Comment: I'm closing this as too broad because the frame of the question is wrong.  I was torn between doing that and answering with a frame challenge explaining that 5e is the wrong system for this, but the fact that any complete answer other than 'don't do this' would be too long for our site made me go for the close instead.

Comment: I have started a chat:https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74330/how-can-i-run-a-game-where-the-players-are-lesser-deities

Comment: @thedarkwanderer do you think this can be answered if the title is changed to match the last sentence: "Are there official rules in 5e for playing as gods, or in earlier editions as well?" ? The answer can be a "No, but this system does...."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're committing to a lot of homework here, but it's possible.  The main thing is going to be to design the "character classes".  What are the powers and abilities for each tier in each branch?  What is needed for a character to advance from each tier to the next in each branch?  Are the tiers already occupied -- i.e. when a character advances, does he take the new position automatically, or does he have to defeat the existing occupant?

I think the rules set will probably work well enough; you need to design the gods in question.  Will they use existing spells, or will those have to be created as well?  Are they a cooperative pantheon, or a squabbling one?  Are they working to the same ends, or do some of them (or even each of them) have additional (or conflicting) goals?

Then, once you've got all of that ready to go, you'll need to decide and design their challenges.  Are they contesting against each other, or against some previous order of things, such as Titans or Primordials or some such?  Or is it more of a grand labors kind of thing, to achieve certain tasks such as preventing the Supervolcano under Yellowstone from erupting, or something like that?

You've got lots of work to do, very ambitious.  Good luck with it all.